# Unable to print correct Calendar on Java

Tags: java, methods, calendar

Can anyone help me find what is wrong with my code? I cannot figure out how to display the correct start day of the month (Note that the January 1, 1900 was a Monday) or to display the correct number of days in the month of February if the year is a leap year.

```
public class Calendar {
/**
 * 
 * 
 * @param s
 * @return 
 */ 
    public static int getMonthNumber(String s){

            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("jan"))
                return 1;
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("feb"))
                return 2;
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("mar"))
                return 3;
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("apr"))
                return 4;
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("may"))
                return 5;
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("jun"))
                return 6;
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("jul"))
                return 7;
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("aug"))
                return 8;
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("sep"))
                return 9;
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("oct"))
                return 10;
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("nov"))
                return 11;
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("dec"))
                return 12;
            else
                System.out.println("Not valid month!");
            return 0;
 }
    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year){
       int month = 0;
        int s = getDaysIn(month, year);
        return year%4==0 && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0); 

    }
    public static int getDaysIn (int month, int year){

        switch (month) {
            case 1:  return 31; 
            case 2:  if(isLeapYear(month)) return 29;
            else return 28;
            case 3:  return 31; 
            case 4:  return 30;
            case 5:  return 31; 
            case 6:  return 30; 
            case 7:  return 31; 
            case 8:  return 31; 
            case 9:  return 30; 
            case 10: return 31; 
            case 11: return 30; 
            case 12: return 31; 
            default: return -1;
    } 
    }
    public static String getMonthName (int month){         
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  return "January";
            case 2:  return "February"; 
            case 3:  return "March";
            case 4:  return "April"; 
            case 5:  return "May"; 
            case 6:  return "June";
            case 7:  return "July"; 
            case 8:  return "August"; 
            case 9:  return "September"; 
            case 10: return "October"; 
            case 11: return "November"; 
            case 12: return "December"; 
            default: return "Invalid month.";
    } 

    }
    public static int getStartDay (int month, int year){
        int days = 0;

        for (int i = 1900; i<year; i++){
            days = days + 365;
            if (isLeapYear(i))
                days = days + 1;}
        for (int i=1; i<month; i++)
            days = days + getDaysIn(month, year);
        int startday = (days + 1)%7+1; 
        return startday;
    }
    public static void displayCalendar(int month, int year){

        String monthname=getMonthName(month);
        int startDay= getStartDay(month, year);
        int monthDays = getDaysIn(month, year);

        System.out.println("   Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat");
        int weekDay = startDay-1;
        for (int i=1; i<=startDay; i=i+1)
            System.out.print("    ");    
        for ( int x=1; x<=monthDays; x++){
           weekDay = weekDay +1;
            if (weekDay>7){
                System.out.println();
            weekDay = 1;}
        System.out.format("   %3d",x);     
    }
        if (weekDay > 7){
            System.out.println();

        }
    }
      public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner c = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.print("Give the first three letters of a month and enter the year: ");
      String month,year;
      month=c.next();
      year=c.next();

      int yearno =Integer.parseInt(year); 

      int monthno = getMonthNumber(month);

      displayCalendar(monthno, yearno);

      }  
    }
```

Comment: You should research the `switch` statement. [The java switch statement.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: And make your question title actually describe your problem.

Comment: And reduce the code to the minimal required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you checked `java.util.Calendar`?

Comment: yes thank you! @Arvin but we can only use the methods that appear in my code

Comment: @filo, kindly find my post

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you can use the `java.util.Calendar`, I would code something like this:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalendarPrinter {

    private Calendar c = null;

    CalendarPrinter(int month, int year ){
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.clear();
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    }

    public String showCalendar(){
        StringBuffer calendarTxt = new StringBuffer("Sun\tMon\tTue\tWed\tThu\tFri\tSat\n");
        int daysInAMonth = c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int firstDayOfWeek = c.getFirstDayOfWeek();
        int i = 1;
        do {
            if (i < c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)){
                calendarTxt.append("\t");
                daysInAMonth++;
            } else {
                calendarTxt.append(firstDayOfWeek+"\t");
                firstDayOfWeek++;
            }
            if (i%7 == 0 && i != 1){
                calendarTxt.append("\n");
            }
            i++;
        } while (i <= daysInAMonth);
        return calendarTxt.toString();
    }

    public static int getMonthNumber(String s){

        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("jan"))
            return 0;
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("feb"))
            return 1;
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("mar"))
            return 2;
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("apr"))
            return 3;
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("may"))
            return 4;
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("jun"))
            return 5;
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("jul"))
            return 6;
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("aug"))
            return 7;
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("sep"))
            return 8;
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("oct"))
            return 9;
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("nov"))
            return 10;
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("dec"))
            return 11;
        else
            System.out.println("Not valid month!");
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Give the first three letters of a month and enter the year: ");
        String month;
        int year;
        month=input.next();
        year=input.nextInt();
        CalendarPrinter c = new CalendarPrinter(getMonthNumber(month), year);
        System.out.println(c.showCalendar());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example just for days of week based on [Zeller's congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence).

[image]

Sample code:

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(days()[dow(8,10,2015)]);
    }
    public static String[] days() {
        return new String[] { 
          "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
          "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
        };
    }
    public static int dow(int d, int m, int y) {
      if (m < 3) {
        m += 12;
        y--;
      }
      return (d + (int)((m+1)*2.6) +  y + (int)(y/4) + 6*(int)(y/100) + (int)(y/400) + 6) % 7;
    }
}
```

Running code [here](https://ideone.com/nVMtHW)

Code reference [here](http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/3350/getting-the-day-of-the-week-without-calendar)